# Calculating geodesics $\mathbb{R}^3-\{(0,0,0)\}$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, isometry, geodesic

I have to calculate the geodesics of the Riemann manifold $(\mathbb{R}^3-\{(0,0,0)\},g)$, where $g$ is the Riemann metric
$$
g=\frac{dx^2+dy^2+dz^2}{x^2+y^2+z^2}
$$
I'm supposed to use that the diffeomorphism $\psi:S^2\times\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3-\{(0,0,0)\}$, $\psi((v_1,v_2,v_3),t)=e^t(v_1,v_2,v_3)$ is an isometry, when we use the product metric in $ S^2\times\mathbb{R}$ and $g$ in $\mathbb{R}^3-\{(0,0,0)\}$. Is it possible to calculate those geodesics using this isometry with out calculating the Christoffel symbols?

Comment: You know the geodesics on the round sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$ and on $\mathbb{R}$.  And you know geodesics on products...

Comment: In $S^2$ the geodesics are constant paths and maximal circunferences. In $\mathbb{R}$ I suppose they are straight lines.

Comment: @Indiano28 Exactly; the other ingredient is that, on a Riemannian product manifold $M_1\times M_2$, geodesics have the form $\gamma(t)=(\gamma_1(t),\gamma_2(t))$, where $\gamma_1,\gamma_2$ are geodesics on $M_1,M_2$ respectively.

Comment: Thank you very much! Then I have geodesics in the first manifold. I suppose that there is a result which affirms that if to manifolds with their respective metrics are isometric then geodesics are the same in both of them? @Kajelad

Comment: @Indiano28 More precisely, the result is that if $\varphi:(M,g)\to (N,h)$ is an isometry and $\gamma:(a,b)\to M$ is a geodesic then $\varphi\circ\gamma$ is also a geodesic. How to show this depends on your definition of geodesic. If you use locally minimizing curves, then it's straightforward to show that $\gamma\circ\varphi$ is also locally minimizing. If you use the Levy-civita connection, then you need to show that the connection is preserved by $\varphi$.

Comment: Thank you very much!